# Is manual driving faster than Ignis driving?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

Is it faster to drive manually or let Ignis drive (No fast travel)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, there's no difference in speed, but manually driving leaves room for error when you need to make turns, which could affect your travel time. Ignis will make necessary turns automatically.

Comment: Won't this work the other way as well? Can't we make corners manually which Ignis wouldn't make because they aren't considered safe enough (risk of getting stuck and the like)?

Comment: @Mast movement is fairly "railed", you can't go out of some specified safe road zone.

Comment: @Mast any turn you can make, Ignis can make. But he will always pick the fastest route. Driving manually means you'll have to make the turns yourself and most likely you'll be spending time checking the map to see *when* you need to turn.

Comment: Sounds like an autonav without downsides, there aren't many of those. Just checking :-)

Comment: It's worth noting that Ignis's driving allows you to spot and gather items on the road or side-of-the road which do not appear on the minimap and would otherwise be missed in manual driving mode.

Ignis, however, pulls over a short distance from where the initial instruction is given.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen one case where manually driving is advantageous: if there's an Imperial dropship on the road (but not so close that you can't get in the car), and you'd rather avoid it than fight it, Ignis won't navigate around it even if he could. He'll plot the shortest route to the destination and drive the car right up to the enemies, and then you'll be committed to the fight. Driving manually, you can take a longer route that avoids the battle, possibly saving time overall.